# Shopware 6 App - Loading product images/thumbnail in listing

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

Hello I want to load more images in the Showpare 6 listing than just the cover.
I want to do it in an app since we are in a cloud environment. I saw something called App Scripts and also if I understood correctly it should be enough to put a `<read>` tag in the `manifest.xml`?

Still I can't figure out how the images are getting loaded in the frontend, anyone has an idea?

I tried to look into App Scripts but I think thats not the right call.
All I need is probably something in my `manifest.xml` like:

`<read>product</read>`

`<update>product</update>`

`<create>product</create>`

`<delete>product</delete>`

but for the `product_listing` and the media associated with the products. Could not find any information about that anyone has an idea?

Comment: I did read a bit more about App Scripts and I think I need a combination of both. I found the `cms-page-loaded` and the `navigation-page-loaded`.

I tried to create a scripts folder within the app and the corresponding directories for the hooks. In the manifest I added the permission for `product` and `product_media`.

But somehow it doesnt seem to work. I could also only find how to add media to the product page in the docs. How can we add the media to the listing page?